# Unable to soft code a username when the profile is updated

Tags: authentication, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Not able to set the username when the profile is updated

Have tried various methods, can get comment user name to update, but not the username on the index or show pages

**Mongoose Movie Schema**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: String,
    title: String,
    director: String,
    review: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
            },
    comments: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Comment"
      }
   ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Movie", MovieSchema);
```

**index.ejs file snippet**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
Movie added by:<br> <a href="/users/<%= movie.author.id %>">
<%= movie.author.username %></a>
</li
```

>

**show.ejs file snippet**

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Director - <%= movie.director %></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        Movie added by - <a href="/users/<%= movie.author.id %>">
        <%= movie.author.username %></a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

**Show route**

```
router.get("/movies/:id", function(req, res){ Movie.findById(req.params.id)
.populate({path: "movies", populate: {path: "author", model: "User"}})  
.populate({path: "comments", populate: {path: "author", model: "User"}})
.exec(function (err, foundReview) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong, please try again");
        res.redirect("/");
    } else {
        res.render("movies/show", {movie: foundReview});
        }
    });
});
```

It either says id is undefined, username is undefined or it is just blank